# Get a key of an array that is inside another array and contains value

Tags: php, arrays, function, output, information-retrieval

I have the following array:

```
$var = array(
  key1 => array(value1, value2, value3),
  key2 => array(value4, value5, value6, value7)
);
```

How can I get the key of an array that contains, for example, `value5`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using a simple `foreach`

```
foreach($var as $k=>$arr)
{
 if(in_array('value5',$arr))
 {
   echo $k;
   break;
 }
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/134935)